# WPF color styles are different per computer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a WPF app with a style in the app.xaml which states

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen"/>
```

This basically highlights the selected row in a DataGrid.

When I run it on my Windows 7, .Net 4.0 computer, the toolbars in the view are their natural color. (Via debug mode in VS or a release exe.)

However, when I put the app on different computer (specifically Windows server 2008) The toolbars around the page are this same colour as the style I stated above. Again using .NET 4.0

I can post screenshots but I think you might get the idea. Is there anything I can do in the code to stop this, or is this specifically a machine setup issue?

Cheers

Comment: The Colors of SystemColors are, as the name implies system dependent. If you want a consistent look, define own static ressources or obtain a full theme and use this as resource.

Comment: seems like you are trying to override the existing values, which may not be predictable on different platforms. you may have other possible options to achieve the same eg. `TextElement.Foreground`

Comment: Different Windows Theme used?